# Django request.body returning data but not request.POST using forms

Tags: python, html, django, forms, python-requests

I'm using forms in Django and trying to get the get the data back using `request.POST`, but this returns an empty dictionary for me: `<QueryDict: {}>`. When using `request.body`, however, I get the raw data back. How can I get the data from `request.POST` as well, because I do not want to work with raw data. The console output of the print statements are put in comments next to them.

forms.py

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First name:', max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last name:')
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def blank(request):
    form = NameForm()
    print(f"request.body: {request.body}") # request.body: b'first_name=Adam&last_name=Smith'
    print(f"request.POST: {request.POST}") # request.POST: <QueryDict: {}>

    return render(request, 'blank.html', {'form': form})
```

blank.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```